# How to judge position of output?

Tags: positioning, line-numbering

To make the chapter title spaced from the above text,its properties have been changed via `\titlespacing`.

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt} %left gap
{10pt} %above gap
{0pt} %bottom gap
```

Aim:
[[color of layout part in the picture is not defined.It just for view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO7Dx.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO7Dx.png)

The question now is: When in a new page the chapter title to be very far away from the header:
[[gap distance too large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HZQF.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HZQF.png)

Need to resolve: When the chapter title is rendered on a new page, the top gap of the chapter title is not rendered.

So I need some means to see if the rendered chapter title is on the first line of the page.

Demo:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%%%%%%%%%%%%% Customize our title format and space %%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{\section}{}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{50pt}{0pt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%% Head of Page for compare gap %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{4pt}
                
\begin{document}
\section{Section-1}
\blindtext
\section{Section-2}
\blindtext
\section{Section-3}
ssss \\
ssss\\
ssss\\
ssss\\
ssss\\
ssss\\
ssss \\
ssss\\
ssss\\
ssss\\
ssss\\
ssss\\
ssss\\
ssss\\
% The gap defined by `\titlespacing` of section would not rendered, but it will be.
\section{Section-4}
\blindtext
\section{Section-5}
ssss \\
ssss\\
ssss\\
ssss\\
ssss\\
ssss\\
ssss \\
ssss\\
ssss\\
ssss\\
ssss\\
ssss\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Do you have a `\chapter` that does not force a new page?? What document class is that? I assume `\titlespacing` is from `titlesec` package but you do not say and the above gives `! Paragraph ended before \ttl@spacing@i was complete` due to missing arguments. What is `chapterIndex` ? what is `\ifnumequal`? Please always post example code in a form people can use to see the issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 1.\chapter wont force a new page. 2.There use our document class which is customized by our group

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I simplify description of issu. Hope it is clear enough.

Comment: @Mahsatshak Please, keep the bug in your demo code. Because without it the whole thread isn't relevant: it is not known, where was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

TeX implements the concept of "discardable items" for breaking paragraph into lines and breaking lines into pages. First case discards horizontal spaces and second one vertical spaces. Example for horizontal spaces: suppose: "word space word space wordX space wordY". If the line is broken immediately after wordX then the following space is discarded and the next line begins with wordY without space before it.

The same concept is in vertical sense. For example, suppose:

```
line
  space 
lineX 
  space-before-title 
title-line
  nobreakable-space 
line 
  space 
line 
  space
```

If TeX decides to break lines to the page immediately after lineX, then space-before-title is discarded and title-line follows at next page without space before it.

If this concept is invisible in your document then some specific macros prohibit it by putting invisible line followed by nobreakable-space before title-line. This is macro-specific problem. Use another macros that don't do that.

**Edit** To your demo document: Remove the `\\` after the last `ssss`. It creates next empty line in the paragraph. The page was broken before this empty line, so you have empty line, space and title line at the next page.

Having `\\` at the end of the paragraph is wrong in all cases. Note that Underfull warning is printed due to this mistake.

**Enlightenment:** you see that doing minimal example is very substantial. Because only such example shows something what the questioner doesn't consider important but this is important.

Comment: thanks for you answer. But i don't  know how to use the concept on my doc, because this space will be inserted in front of chapter title.

Comment: My answer is about the fact that TeX does not keep such space at the beginning of the page by default and that there must be something specific in your macros. You can show a minimal example and then LateX experts will be able to inspect it and give more concrete solution.

Comment: thanks for your expound. In above i have explained this "space or gap" was defined in chapter's property, so the fact you raised not helping me.

Comment: If you want concrete solution, give concrete minimal example. Not only a description of your problem. Minimal example can be copied and pasted to another computer, then run TeX and then people see the same problem in their computer. Then people can advice you. You didn't give such example.

Comment: ok, get it. I will update the issu later with example you ask for.

Comment: upgrade of demo is finished!

Comment: @Mahsatshak I upgraded my answer.