# How can i ignore or clear remaining floats?

Tags: floats, endfloat

Clear all remaining floats from previous section whenever I start a Chapter ？

My clue: found a code that reads and prints all remaining floats from @deferlist

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\flushqueue}{\bgroup
\let\mylist=\@deferlist
\gdef\@deferlist{}\par
\loop\@next\mybox\mylist{}{\let\mybox=\voidb@x}%
\ifvoid\mybox
\else
\ifnum\count\mybox<64
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \unvbox\mybox
    \end{figure}\par
\else
    \begin{table}[ht!]
        \unvbox\mybox
    \end{table}\par
\fi
\repeat
\egroup}
\makeatother
```

My current thoughts: Is it okay to just clear the @deferlist?But I don't know how to empty or ignore the floats inside

Comment: why do you want to throw away your floats?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Because my custom chapter will have an inexplicable gap at the top of each print, and the gap will only disappear after calling \clearpage (the gap is still there after calling \newpage), so I realize logical judgment by interpreting \clearpage is the gap created by remaining float. Or is it a problem caused by a blank line, I don't have a clear proof, so it's still in an exploratory stage. Here is my original question link:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661980/how-to-judge-position-of-output

Comment: well as the answer to your other question says: using `\\` at the end of paragraphs is wrong. But beside this it doesn't explain why you want to throw away content.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The key point is not to link the question, it is just my initial guess and the gap in the example will only appear before the first chapter, other chapters are normal. It shows that the example is invalid and does not reproduce my problem.
The latest problem is that the gap appears before all my chapters, and these gaps can only be passed through \clearpage (defined as output all floats and call \newpage), so I guess the gap is output in the new generated by \clearpage page. So I want to define a new command: discard the data processed by \clearpage and not use \newpage.

Comment: Be careful of the XY problem. If you really want to *solve* your original problem, generally the best way is to try to create a minimal working example that demonstrates *that problem* instead of making guesses of the cause (LaTeX is very complicated, so when something goes wrong it's not easy to guess what's going on)